# Select multi sibling elements using one selector

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm crawling posts using Scrapy & Python, and I found some data which I can't handle:

```
<li class="a b">Type1</li>
<li class="c">Type2</li>
<li class="c">Type2</li>
<li class="c">Type2</li>
<li class="a">Titles Type3</li>
<li class="c">Type4</li>
<li class="c">Type4</li>
<li class="c">Type4</li>
```

I want to get all Type4 elements, and there are random size of type2 and 4, and one type1 and one type3.
I've tried `response.css('.c + .a +.c')` but this will only get the first Type4 element.
Could anyone come up with some advices or ideas?

Comment: try this `response.css('.c + .a ~.c')`

Comment: WOW! You are amazing! Thank you so much! @GautamNaik

Answer (score 0):

try this response.css('.c + .a ~.c')

**+** means select the next sibling only.Its called sibling selector.

**~** means select all next siblings.Its called general sibling selectors.

Refer the link [Taming Advanced CSS Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/) for more info